# How to make \includegraphics actually execute \includesvg

Tags: macros, includegraphics, alias

I have a very special problem: the Tikz output from [matchcha.io](https://mathcha.io) uses `\includegraphics` to include `.svg` images, but it seems that you need to use `\includesvg` to do this.

E.g., a line in my Tikz drawing looks like this:

```
%Image [id:dp19508275324868107] 
\draw (104.75,142.67) node  {\includegraphics[width=99.88pt,height=70pt]{cube_back.svg}};
```

I do not want to replace all commands and just remap the function `\includegraphics` to do the job of `\includesvg`.

I could not get this to work though... can you help? Thanks!

This does not work: `\renewcommand{\includesvg}{\includegraphics}`

Comment: naturally `\renewcommand{\includesvg}{\includegraphics} ` will have no effect at all if the document does not use `\includesvg`

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks :) I tried it, but no success :/

Comment: @CarLaTeX no worries, I can manually replace it, but I thought there may be a better way

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). I think what you need is `\renewcommand{\includegraphics}{\includesvg}` (ie, you want to rededine `\includegraphics` instead of redefinng `\includesvg` as in your question). You way want to keep this within a group (either by using an extra brace roup `{...}`, or by using `\begingroup ... \endgroup`) so that this change is limited to just around the code where you need this.

Comment: If that does not solve your issue, I suggest you compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.